# Why can't an n-bit hash be cracked by hashing every single n-bit plaintext?

Tags: cryptography, hash

I'm wondering why it's so hard to find collisions for cryptographic hashes.

Take for example a hash function that outputs a `64` bit hash.

In order to find collisions, if you feed the function every single `65` bit string possible, aren't you guaranteed to find a collision? The hash function has to turn `65` bits into `64` bits so is has to find some collisions.

Can't a collision be found in a pretty straightforward way using this technique?

I understand computing all of them will take a lot of time but it seems pretty reasonable to do so and create a database index to store them in so hashes can be broken.

Comment: Have a look at how much 2^64 already is and take into consideration that common cryptgraphic hashes are  >128 Bit.

Comment: Also note that as you start to get into the 256-bit range, the mere cost of running a counter from 0 to 2^256-1 in terms of minimum theoretical energy is on the order of a good chunk of the nuclear energy in the galaxy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Although you would expect (statistically) to find a collision already after about 2^32 tries.

If you have a hash of 160 bit length you would have to try 2^80 combinations (on average) to find a collision. But still, with today computing power trying 2^80 combinations will take too long for you to become old enough to see the collision :-)

That's pretty much all about it. Making the bits so many that it just takes to long to try all necessary combinations out.

Comment: @RobW: If you only need a collision between *any* two inputs, then the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) applies, and you only need to try about `sqrt(2*2^n) = 2^(n/2+1/2)` inputs to find a collision for an `n` bit hash.

Comment: 2⁸⁰ may sound like a lot. But compare that to the number of hashes computed by Bitcoin. Bitcoin has computed approximately 2⁸³ hashes in 2015.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That ("any collision") is also a way to read the question. I was assuming that the OP wanted to construct a table and then look up a specific hash in that table, which would require trying half of the possibilities (2^63 for the example of the OP).

Comment: @kasperd Didn't know that number. Although it makes clear why the trend goes to saying 2^80 is no longer enough.

Comment: @kasperd, and that still is a lot. That number has only been achieved for millions of US dollars over years. But yes, for comfort it is nice to have even more than the edge of possibility, to protect against future developments.

Comment: @kasperd: That still means that your 160bit hash is safe for at least 6 years (or roughly a year if everyone on the planet join forces to attack you)

Comment: 2^80 is about one month for the bitcoin mining network.

Answer (score 4):

fr00tyl00p explained it pretty nicely, so I'll just dump some numbers to make clear how much data that would be.

Lets stay with your example (Every 65 bit value hashed to 64 bit).
65 bit can hold 2^65 different values = 36.893.488.147.419.103.232.
So you'd need to save at least 2^65 * 64 bit.
You may also need some sort of index but lets ignore that for now.

This would require about 256 pebibyte, or 262144 petabyte data. And this is for only 64 bit hashes and without any form of index.

Comment: wow that's an insane amount of memory. But probably in the not too distant future, it won't be as insane

Comment: Also: if you can try one combination per nanosecond, this will take 2^65/(1e9*86400*365) = 1170 years. Too long to wait for.

Comment: Not if you're calculating the Meaning of Life, The Universe and Everything

Comment: 1PB is only 2⁵⁰ bytes. 2⁶⁰ bytes is 1EB. You don't actually need to store 2⁶⁴ hashes though. If you combine a birthday attack with rainbow tables, you only need to store 2¹⁶ hashes in order to produce a collision on a hash function with 64 bits of output.

Comment: 1) You'll find a collision after around 2^32 computations (birthday problem), so even with your naive algorithm you'd only need a few GB. 2) If you use a proper algorithm (cycle finding, distinguished points etc.) for collision finding you barely need any storage at all.